# JRXlsxExporter : value in cell is not visible properly

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am using JRXlsxExporter to export an xlsx report, Below is the java side code,

```
JRXlsxExporter xlsExporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
    AbstractXlsReportConfiguration config = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
    config.setOnePagePerSheet(false);
    config.setDetectCellType(Boolean.TRUE);
    config.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true);
    config.setCollapseRowSpan(Boolean.TRUE);
    config.setIgnoreGraphics(Boolean.TRUE);
    config.setWrapText(Boolean.TRUE);
    config.setColumnWidthRatio(2.0F);
    config.setShowGridLines(Boolean.FALSE);
    config.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenColumns(Boolean.TRUE);
    config.setFontSizeFixEnabled(false);
    config.setSheetNames(new String[]{"Sheet1"});
    List<ExporterInputItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(new SimpleExporterInputItem(jPrint, config));
    xlsExporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(items));
    xlsExporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(path));
    xlsExporter.exportReport();
```

But when I opened the generated xlsx file it looks like this.
[image]

The xlsx doesn't show the text properly for the cell where more than 2 lines are there.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Try to see if config.setFontSizeFixEnabled(true) makes any difference.

Comment: @dada67, thanks for your reply,But this also doesn't help,the generated report is same as earlier one,no different.